# understanding ContextVar object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, python-contextvars

Here is a simple echo server that works correctly as expected - by "correctly" I mean, in the output we see that every user gets its own unique address when echoing inside `listen_for_messages`.

```py
import asyncio
from contextvars import ContextVar


class Server:
    user_address = ContextVar("user_address")

    def __init__(self, host: str, port: int):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    async def start_server(self):
        server = await asyncio.start_server(self._on_connected, self.host, self.port)
        await server.serve_forever()

    def _on_connected(self, reader, writer):
        self.user_address.set(writer.get_extra_info("peername"))
        asyncio.create_task(self.listen_for_messages(reader))

    async def listen_for_messages(self, reader):
        while data := await reader.readline():
            print(f"Got message {data} from {self.user_address.get()}")

async def main():
    server = Server("127.0.0.1", 9000)
    await server.start_server()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Now look at where we set the context var object's value. My question is why it is working correctly?

To my understanding, every "`Task`" will have its own copy of the `ContextVar`. If the line:

```py
self.user_address.set(writer.get_extra_info("peername"))
```

was inside `listen_for_messages` coroutine, I would not ask this question, since we explicitly created a new task for it. Even [if `_on_connected` was a coroutine function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.start_server), I wouldn't ask too. because:

> `client_connected_cb` can be a plain callable or a coroutine function; if it is a **coroutine function, it will be automatically scheduled as a Task**.

But it's inside the `_on_connected` (plain) function and it's not a new task. Before creating the new `listen_for_messages`  task, we have a parent Task of `main()` (which `.run()` function created). I guessed it shouldn't work and the function simply just overrides the value (because it's just part of a single parent Task)

I would appreciate if you tell me which part of my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asyncio framework in this case calls the `_on_connected` callback with a new context copy - that is the expected behavior for ContextVars anyway - a callback chain started by the asyncio loop is counted as a "new task"  as far as COntextvars are concerned.

The callback itself, either for step over a co-routine, or an sync callback is executed through a call to `context.run`, which creates a new context  -
the relevant "under the hood" code is at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9c73a9acec095c05a178e7dff638f7d9769318f3/Lib/asyncio/events.py#L84

Comment: I thought the callback is called here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/streams.py#L245 and because it's a plain function (not a coroutine), it's not scheduled.

Comment: It goes though there, yes, but everything an asyncio loop does is wrapped in an opaque " handle" object, which is the only thing called in the asyncio loop `_run_once` method - check the `asyncio.base_events.py`  file. The callback is wrapped into a `Handle` elsewhere.

Comment: Oh I got you. As for last question could you please confirm this: when we start the server [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/selector_events.py#L159)(it has our callback as a parameter), asyncio registers a socket [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/selector_events.py#L274), then because they're all get passed to `Handle` constructor, [a new copy of the current context is created](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9c73a9acec095c05a178e7dff638f7d9769318f3/Lib/asyncio/events.py#L34) for that.

Comment: Yes, that copy is created - but even if it was not, the `context.run` method , called in `Handle._run` will _also_ create a copy of the current context.